# Solving the equation $g\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{2 + \sin \left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

[image]

My approach is as follow

$g\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{2 + \sin \left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)}} \Rightarrow g'\left( x \right) =  - \frac{{\cos \left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) \times f'\left( x \right)}}{{{{\left( {2 + \sin \left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)} \right)}^2}}}$

${\alpha _1} = 0;g\left( 0 \right) = \frac{1}{{2 + \sin \left( {f\left( 0 \right)} \right)}} = \frac{2}{5} \Rightarrow 5 = 4 + 2\sin \left( {f\left( 0 \right)} \right) \Rightarrow \sin \left( {f\left( 0 \right)} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$

$f\left( 0 \right) \in \left( {0,\frac{\pi }{2}} \right)\& f\left( 0 \right) = \frac{\pi }{6}$

$f\left( x \right) = 6\pi {x^3} + b{x^2} + cx + d \Rightarrow f\left( 0 \right) = d = \frac{\pi }{6} \Rightarrow f'\left( x \right) = 18\pi {x^2} + 2bx + c$

$f'\left( {{\alpha _1} = 0} \right) = c = 0 \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = 6\pi {x^3} + b{x^2} + \frac{\pi }{6}$

$\frac{1}{{g\left( {{\alpha _5}} \right)}} = \frac{1}{{g\left( {{\alpha _2}} \right)}} + \frac{1}{2}$

How do I approach.

We know that ${g_{\max }} = 1\& {g_{\min }} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Is this from a book? It's really unclear and written badly. Does this mean that $g(x)$ has extremum at the points $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$ and that all these extrema are positive? Or that $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$ lists only the positive ones and there may be others which aren't positive? The data is scattered throughout the question without any organization. (And how about "Let $f(x)$ be.." etc?). Anyway, I assume this is from your book, so it isn't your fault, but since one shouldn't use images but Mathjax, you can try and edit it into something clear, if you do understand the intention.

Comment: It is from korean csat paper , i copied it from internet.

Comment: I suggest you remove the image and type it with Mathjax instead. For two reasons: first, one is not supposed to use images for writing text; second, this will give you a chance to make the question clearer.